# How to force refresh the gantt

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion, gantt-chart

I would like refresh the gantt after some data get updated so at first i did it the react way by calling 
**forceUpdate()** and i expected **taskbarTemplate** will trigger as a consequence but that didn't happen.
I've made this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6lscfc) showing the issue: the expected result is the change of items color to green when the Change color button is clicked ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/StsPnKE.gifv)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve your requirement by using refresh method of Gantt control. Please find the below code example.

```
<button type="button" onClick={ev => {
        this.itemBgColor = 'green';
        var obj = document.getElementById('Default').ej2_instances[0];
        obj.refresh();
}}>Change color</button>
```

Sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6lscfc-rzsakm?file=index.js